# Visualization tools for REST-based services

Tags: proxy, http, http-proxy

Let's say there is a cluster/set of processes that communicate via REST/HTTP (that could describe a whole lot of products these days). What's a good and simple way to view the communication among them in some sort of a nice visual tool? They may be Zookeeper-orchestrated, but not necessarily. (Additionally, if they are on the same machine, ideally I could use netstat to discover who calls whom - would be nice if it was all somehow available). Has to work on Linux.

Yes, I know I can use proxies, etc., but that needs a bunch of manual work. Wireshark and related are even more work. Am wondering if there's a more turnkey solution for something like that.

One approach is just a Wireshark-based, but geared towards just showing HTTP traffic with certain criteria that already works.

The reason Zookeeper is mentioned is perhaps another way is to interrogate Zookeeper, and replace ports in there with proxy ports, and route all traffic through them - but again, I'd like something that already works.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to know who calls whom (not the details of what was said), you could increase logging at the network level via iptables, then collect the syslogs centrally, and parse them into whatever form you need. Or you could use something like ntop/nprobe to gather summarized connection data at each host, then feed that to a central NetFlow report tool. Depending on your environment, you could even collect that data from your network hardware.

If you need to know more about what was said, you'll need proxies, although they can be simple ones running on the same server, feeding their logs to a central server for analysis.

The best solution would be to modify your software to include its own logging capability, even if it only happened in "debug mode", so you could use it to fix problems in the future as well.

See also:
http://www.tokiwinter.com/adding-logging-to-iptables-under-centos/